# What's the odds of Selvala's parley granting 2 or more mana?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I am trying to figure out what are the chance if getting 2 or more mana after parleying [Selvala, Explorer Returned](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Selvala%2C%20Explorer%20Returned), assuming that using commander/EDH one third of the deck is land and that at least four people are playing. Mainly curious after my friends mentioned way to go infinite if I could reliably generate mana.

Comment: I'm not sure how "infinite" it would be, since everyone will be drawing cards.  At some point people will run out of cards and lose.

Comment: The answer to this question also depends on how many people you are playing with.

Comment: Lets assume its a four player game, and I know it won't be infinite per say I just wanted to know the probability

Comment: I think that assuming that only 1/4 of a deck is land in EDH is unrealistic. Going below 1/3 is already risky, and 2/5 is common.

Comment: I said assuming a one land to 3 nonland ratio, not one to four

Comment: @PeterKwiatek 1 land to 3 nonland ratio means that 1/4 of the deck is land, and 3/4 of the deck is nonland.

Comment: @Rainbolt My bad, i got confused i meant a third of the deck is land

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the situation you describe, each player reveals their card independently, and you get mana equal to the number of non-land cards revealed. This is called a [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), with `N = 4` and `P = 2/3` in your particular case. So, the probability of getting exactly `k` mana is `(4 choose k) * (2/3) ^ k * (1/3) ^ (n - k)`. You are specifically looking for the probability of getting at least a certain amount of mana, so you are looking for the Cumulative Binomial Distribution. To get the probability of getting *at least* a certain amount of mana, you simply add up the probabilities for each amount that is at least that number. So, to calculate that for your particular situation, you would calculate

[image: Sum from k = 2 to 4 of (4 choose k) * (2 / 3) ^ k * (1 / 3) ^ (4 - k)]

The fully general formula for this, if you want to get at least M mana is

[image: Sum from k = M to N of (N choose k) * (P) ^ k * (1 - P) ^ (N - k)]

In the particular case of `k = 2`, we can instead simply consider the cases where you *don't* get at least 2 mana, and then subtract that total probability from 1. For each player, the probability of only that player flipping a non-land is 2/3 * (1/3) ^ (N - 1). The probability of every player flipping a land is (1/3) ^ N. So, the total probability of getting at least two mana is

[image: 1 - (N * 2/3 * (1/3) ^ (N - 1) + (1/3) ^ N)]

For 4 players, this probability is 8/9.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for also, how would you use this to figure out the probability of generating x mana

Comment: I added a fully general formula

Comment: What does ^ mean?

Comment: That's exponentiation. We don't have MathJax on this site, so I don't really have a better way to represent it.

Comment: You could use a Latex generator to create a static image: http://arachnoid.com/latex/?equ=%5Ctextrm%7BSum%20from%20%7D%20k%20%3D%20M%20%5Ctextrm%7B%20to%20%7D%20N%20%5Ctextrm%7B%20of%20%7D%20(N%20%5Ctextrm%7B%20choose%20%7D%20k)%20%5Ctimes%20P%5E%7Bk%7D%20%5Ctimes%20(1%20-%20P)%5E%7B(N%20-%20k)%7D for middle equation, http://arachnoid.com/latex/?equ=1%20-%20(N%20%5Ctimes%20%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%7D%20%5Ctimes%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%5E%7B(N%20-%201)%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%5EN) for the last one.

Comment: OK, I've made the large equations into LaTeX images.